# Deliver variable between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, mouseevent, clearinterval

I'm using this simple script to create some slider which is starting on mouseenter and which should stops on mouseleave:

```
$( ".grid-item" ).mouseenter(function() {

  var slides = $(this).find( ".slide-image" ), 
      counter = 0;

  var test = setInterval(function(){
  slides.removeClass('active');
  slides.eq(counter).addClass('active');
  counter++;

  if (counter > slides.length) {counter = 0;};
  }, 600);

}).mouseleave(function() {

  clearInterval(test);
  // $( ".slide-image" ).removeClass('active');

});
```

The Slider starts quite fine but on the mouseleave-event I'm getting the console error **"Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"**. I think thats because the variable of the interval is not delivered in the second function. Is there any solution?

[Check out my CodePen!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBvPgg) (It works fine here)

Comment: Define `test` outside event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable `test` outside the function

```
var test;
$( ".grid-item" ).mouseenter(function() {

  var slides = $(this).find( ".slide-image" ), 
      counter = 0;

  test = setInterval(function(){
  slides.removeClass('active');
  slides.eq(counter).addClass('active');
  counter++;

  if (counter > slides.length) {counter = 0;};
  }, 600);

}).mouseleave(function() {

  clearInterval(test);
  // $( ".slide-image" ).removeClass('active');

});
```